# How to create an SSD persistent disk boot disk in gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

How can I create a boot disk type of SSD persistent disk using gcloud?

From the console I can create a VM instance with SSD persistent disk from the image. I am not able to do it using gcloud.

```
gcloud compute instances create instance1 --image img_name1 --image-project project_id --machine-type=type_value1 --zone=${CONFIG_zone}
```

By defaults it is creating a Standard Persistent Disk.

Comment: Never mind. Figure it out.   --boot-disk-type=BOOT_DISK_TYPE

Answer (score 4):

You are right, the default disk type for boot disks in new compute engine instances is "Standard persistent disk"

Try to use the optional parameter "--boot-disk-type" for the "gcloud compute instances create" command as described in the [gcloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create).

With the following command I created a debian test instance with ssd boot disk:

```
gcloud compute instances create test-vm  --machine-type=f1-micro \
 --zone=europe-west4-b --boot-disk-type=pd-ssd
```

You can get the available disk types for each zone via the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute disk-types list
```

The disk typ "pd-ssd" however seems to be available in all zones.